# Building NodeJS Electron On Screen Keyboard, Can't Send KeyStroke

Tags: java, node.js, electron

So the idea is this: build an on screen keyboard app for computers that can turn into tablets like the Lenovo Yoga. Something cross platform so we don't have to put up with windows 10.

So I've installed NodeJS with Electron for window management on Linux Mint 17.3. I've got the windows and elements all working fine, but when it comes to putting a keystroke into another application I fall flat.

My only idea so far is to use an external java jar that uses Robot (kbm-robot NodeJS component) to send system wide keystrokes. First send alt and tab, then the key I want, but it takes a long time (for keystrokes) and is very unstable (losing the correct window focus etc).

Has anyone got an ideas for something more stable? Linux only solutions accepted!

If anyone is interested in the source, I'll happily put it up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a `node-gyp` package that uses:

```
xdotool key <key>
```

Where `<key>` can be `a`, or `F1`, or `Control+A`.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/how-to-inject-keystrokes-via-a-shell-script)

**EDIT:** It doesn't look like there's a no focus option for electron though, so I'm not sure what you'll be able to do for that.

Comment: @computeiro Yeah but OP said Linux only solutions are fine

Comment: Yep Linux only is fine. There was something that didn't work with this one, but I can't remember what now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an alternative to the suggested 'kbm-robot'. It is a very small and still cross platform library to send keys to your operational system called 'node-key-sender'.

Install it with `npm install --save-dev node-key-sender`.

And send a key to the keyboard using:

```
var ks = require('node-key-sender');
ks.sendKey('a');
```

Check out the documentation page for other keys: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender.

Comment: Great, I'll check it out. Thank you for the idea!